# presentModalViewController:animated: crash after dismiss

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, crash

I'm currently having an issue with `UIViewController`'s `presentModalViewController:animated:`.

I use the following code to set up and show the modal view controller:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
AddSerialController *serialController = [[AddSerialController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddSerial" bundle:nil];
[navigationController pushViewController:serialController animated:NO];

[self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

[serialController release];
[navigationController release];
```

The Application (running in iPhone Simulator) crashes as soon as `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is called. GDB says it crashes at `objc_msgSend`.

If I comment out the last line of code (release of the navigation controller) everything works but I'm leaking a `UINavigationController` (as expected).

What the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a UINavigationController, you should give it a root view controller:

> `AddSerialController *serialController = [[AddSerialController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddSerial" bundle:nil];`
>
> `UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:serialController];`
>
> `[serialController release];`
>
> `[self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];`
>
> `[navigationController release];`

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Actually, the mistake was further down the road. I had some custom UITableViewCells in a table view which apparently caused the -release-problem. If the navigation controller gets released some ugly things happen to the cells - I still have to investigate what happens exactly.

I'll mark this question as answered anyway - there is nothing left to fix in the presentModalViewController:animated:-part (except the root view controller thing, thanks!), so I'll maybe post another question concerning these UITableViewCell issues later.